# How to set jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a big problem to get a id value from a text field and i am using a method like

```
$(".testfiroz").mouseover(function() {
       cont = $(this).next().text();
       //alert(cont);
       var k=cont.toString();//k=3
       //alert(k);
       var scrollTop     = $(window).scrollTop(),
       elementOffset =$("'#"+k+"'").offset().top,
       distance      = (elementOffset - scrollTop);                              
       alert(distance);
```

But i cannot set like this  $('#9').nothig alert

Comment: At least try: `$("#"+k)`

Comment: get value using like this elementOffset =$("'#"+k+"'").offset().top,

Comment: `$("#"+k)` will match in your example an element with attribute ID equal `3` IF it exists in DOM. When i ask you `What does mean???` i was expectig you to describe what doesn't work. Any error in console? Etc...

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with element id. It starts with a number here. Elements' id must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods ("."). So, you should start your id with a valid one.

Comment: i am adding res_ infront of my id.now its like elementOffset =$("'#res_"+k+"'").offset().top; but still not work

Comment: now iam change id like  $("'#res_"+k+"'").but not work

Comment: ID starting with number is valid following HTML5 specs and would be valid in CSS4.

Answer (score 0):

you  are getting value from input it comes like string no need of vl.toString(). need to convert as integer. so here **+** automatically convert the input value as integer. try this once.

```
$(".testfiroz").mouseover(function() {
           var k = +$(this).next().text();
           var scrollTop     = $(window).scrollTop();
           var elementOffset =$("#"+k).offset().top;
           var distance      = (elementOffset - scrollTop);                              
           alert(distance);
    }
```

Comment: replace comma(,) with semi-colon(;)

Answer (score 0):

Check this:
**<kbd>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DKQT8/)</kbd>**

And this <kbd>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DKQT8/1/)</kbd> will throw an error.
There is something with your id selector, `cont` takes the text value form an element, if it contains a white space it cannot be used as id selector. Check your browser console for errors.